# Insetr values into HashBasedTable

Tags: java

I want to create a data structure this way:

```
'AF' => { :name => 'Afghanistan', :alpha3 => 'AFG', :numeric => '004' },
```

I tried this:

```
Table<String, String, Integer> table = HashBasedTable.create();
    Map<String, Table<String, String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    table.put("AF", "Afghanistan", 004);
    map.put("AF", new  HashBasedTable('Afghanistan', 'AFG', '004'));
```

What is the proper way to insert values into HashBasedTable? I can't find a solution.

Comment: Wouldn't it make much more sense to create a class holding your three props and put that into a normal map?

Answer (score 1):

From your code I cannot see why a regular `Map` cannot do the job here. Create the `Airport` class and then put (using a key) those objects inside a `Map` that fits your needs.

````java
class Airport{
        String title, code;

        Airport(String title, String code){
            this.title=title;
            this.code=code;
        }
}

Then somewhere in your code you can create your map and add your objects.

```java
Airport afg = new Airport("Afganistan", "AFG");
String key = "004";
Map<String,Airport> airports = new HashMap<>();
airports.put(key,afg);
````